# How to prove this Stirling related equation

Tags: inequality, summation

Here is what I need to prove, but have no idea were to start. I know there is some connection with the [Stirling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) theorem.

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{d}\binom{m}{i} \leq \left ( \frac{em}{d} \right )^{d}
$$

for $$ m \geq d$$

I tried to open the sum and start from the right side of the equation but I achieved nothing. I think there is also some connection to Sauer Shelah Lemma.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the Sauer Shelah Lemma isn't it?

There are proofs at the link below; one of which uses a "shifting technique" and the other induction on $m+d$.

http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~hungngo/classes/2011/Fall-694/lectures/vcd.pdf

See references therein to trace the history.

Comment: yes it is, thank you, not an easy one.